# Wordpress Website Choppy/Jittery/Laggy Scrolling

Tags: wordpress, scroll

I have been working on my website for a month. I was busy designing some pages and yesterday I tried taking a tour of what I have created. The homepage of my website exhibits choppy scrolling on Chrome and Opera…but it works fine on Firefox and IE/Edge.

I tried to deactivate all the plugins excluding Brizy Pro as the website was designed on that. But there was still the “choppy scrolling” issue coming up.

I am using Blocksy theme. What I have realised that as soon as I select the Brizy template while editing Homepage, the header and footer goes away and the homepage scrolling becomes smooth again.

I have read numerous answers to similar problems but none of them worked for me. I can’t afford to change the theme now as I have nearly completed the whole website. Also, the issue is just on Chrome and Opera for some reason.

My website is http://hhfa.in

I am a novice and have near to zero knowledge of coding. But I can follow instructions very well. Please help!

Points to remember:

1. Only Chrome and Opera Browsers exhibiting this issue.
2. On Mobile, the scrolling seems to be fine but the "Anchor link" taking user to the footer (for contact info) is still creating Choppy issue.
3. This problem was initially not there. It suddenly started a couple of days back.
4. I have tried to deactivate every plugin accept Brizy builder and the problem still remains.
5. When I change template to Brizy template (instead of the main theme), the problem goes away.

Other pages seem to be fine but even though they have a very very low choppiness at the top of the page.

I can't change the theme. An intensive online search suggested that the issue can be either STICKY HEADER, or a Javascript conflict, or a wrong CSS.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this on some of my websites built with Brizy on Blocksy theme. For my case, it was due to some bugs from Brizy relating to the Fixed\Animated parallax scrolling. Try changing it to None and see if it's better. Consider updating to their latest plugin version.